# Perl as transparent proxy for child process/app

Tags: perl, tcp

How to make perl script transparent proxy for sub-process (non perl app) it starts?

There are a few programs to "socksify" applications via custom libraries and LD_PRELOAD.
It seems to be closest thing to what I want.

I DO NOT want to run any kind of permanent server/service.

Answer (score 2):

The socksify wrapper usually expects to redirect traffic to a SOCKS proxy, so you can use the [IO::Socket::Socks](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::Socks) module to implement a SOCKS5-server in perl and handle the incoming application network traffic any way you want.

[POE::Component::Proxy::SOCKS](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Component::Proxy::SOCKS) with SOCKS4a might be an alternative.

Comment: Could you recommend wrapper redirecting to **UNIX socket** (filesystem based) instead of TCP socket? [I hope for even better fit answer]